# Invalid character in jquery.js (1.9.1) with Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

Help me - I am going crazy. I have an ASP.Net MVC website with Telerik (2015.3.1111) controls. A couple of pages are throwing an error in IE (not in Chrome). The really weird thing is that it is about the jquery.js file itself! Stops on the last line with  `"Invalid Character"`

Telerik has a copy of jquery in its own folder, that is (looking at it) 1.9.1

I don't understand at all - all the other pages work, so JQuery MUST work!

Any clues?

Comment: Check to make sure that the file is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: It is. I specifically resaved it. same issue.